# getChildAt returns null

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout with programmatically added children:

```
for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
            final AnswerView answerView = new AnswerView(getContext(), i);
            addView(answerView);
}
```

Then I'm trying to access random child:

```
private void updateOpenAnswer() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>() {

            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                return API.getOpenAnswer();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer answerIndex) {
                super.onPostExecute(answerIndex);

                Log.i(TAG, "Child count: " + getChildCount());

                if (answerIndex != -1) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Open answer: " + answerIndex);
                    final AnswerView answerView = (AnswerView) getChildAt(answerIndex);
                    if (answerView != null) {
                        answerView.setAnswerOpen(true);
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Null at " + answerIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }
```

updateOpenAnswer is called once in a second in runnable.
And for some calls of updateOpenAnswer getChildAt returns null and getChildCount returns 0! For example, null for 2 and 3, and not null for 0,1,4,5. The views at 2 and 3 really exist and I see them. Why it returns null?

Comment: What does getChildCount() return?

Comment: Hmm, sometimes it returns 0… And sometimes 6.

Comment: @RankoR add here more code please.

Comment: @RankoR do you perform in you app scrolling down/up?

Comment: @sajmon_d no, I see all the child views in one screen

Comment: so add condition that if (getChildCount() > 0) { do all work } and look like app will work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26111/discussion-between-rankor-and-sajmon-d)

Answer (score 1):

> final AnswerView answerView = new AnswerView(getContext(), i);

Most likely problem is `getContext()` that returns null. Try to change it to

```
YourActivity.this // this also returns Context
```

And now it should works.

### Update:

Don't remember that `getChildAt()` will return a view only for the positions which are displaying. So if you are scrolling and want to get child that is not "in View" null will be returned.

Comment: The views are created in the another view

Comment: @RankoR where you are putting your code (in some class) use ThisActivityClass.this

Comment: If `getContext()` was null, an NPE should be thrown upon adding the Views. The OP is asking why `getChildAt()` sometimes returns null.

Comment: BTW, I've checked, in the debugger — context is not null in all cases. So, it's not the reason of this strange behavior.

Comment: so this is very strange behaviour